# Why 1 out of 5 AUC cross validation score is very low?

Tags: classification, python, cross-validation, auc, boosting

I am using xgboost model for binary classification problem. I am using 5 fold cross-validation (stratified as class imbalance) which results into the following.

```
xgb_model = xgb.XGBClassifier(objective="binary:logistic", random_state=42)

scores = cross_val_score(xgb_model, X, y, scoring="roc_auc", cv=5)

>> [0.97167546 0.96833211 0.58207582 0.90730687 0.93105652]
```

Why is one out of the above five AUC scores very low(~0.58207582)?

Comment: I would investigate the contents of the fold. Perhaps they are harder examples, for whatever reason? Or by coincidence they're all different in some way from the training data for that fold?

Comment: Is it reproducible with a different random state value (or without any)?

Comment: @itdxer Yes, I just checked and it gives the same results.

Comment: Can you please provide a reproducible example?